# How to create a pagination by selecting categories?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I'm trying learn how to make a simple pagination.. for the first launch (index.php) it's success,
then i click the button CATEGORIES to show the products by category, it's still success..
But when i click the next page, let say page number 5, it's actually jump to the page number 5
but not in the CATEGORIES, it's back to the main page. I know it's because of this echo a href='index.php',
but i'm a beginner here, just start with php and javascript about a week ago,
so i need you "JUST CORRECT MY CODE", please don't give me a bunch of code like javascript that i'm just start to learning.

```
<!--index.php-->
<!doctype html>
<?php include ("functions/functions.php"); ?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>

    <!--NAV BUTTON-BY CATEGORY-->   
    <ul id="cats">
      <?php getCats(); ?>
    </ul>

    <!--SHOWING PRODUCTS-->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <?php getPro(); ?>  <!--FIRST LAUNCH (index.php)-->
        <?php getCatPro(); ?>  <!--GETTING THE PRODUCTS BY CATEGORIES-->
    </div>

</body>
</html>



//functions.php
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","justLearning");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
   echo "The connection was not established: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

//GETTING THE CATEGORIES (
function getCats(){
    global $con;
    $get_cats = "select * from categories";
    $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);
    while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
        $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
        $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];
    echo "<li><button><a href='index.php?cat=$cat_id'>$cat_title</a></button></li>";
    }
}

//FIRST LAUNCH (index.php)
function getPro(){
    if(!isset($_GET['cat'])){
    if(!isset($_GET['brand'])){
        global $con;
        $per_page=9;
        if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
        $page = $_GET["page"];
        }
        else {
        $page=1;
        }
        $start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY product_id DESC LIMIT $start_from, $per_page";
        $result = mysqli_query ($con, $query);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $pro_title = $row['product_title'];
            $pro_image = $row['product_image'];

            echo "<div id='product'>
                    <h3>$pro_title</h3>
                    <img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_image' width='135' height='145'/>
                  </div>";
        }
            $query = "select * from products";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
            $total_records = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);
                echo "<a href='index.php?page=1'>".'First Page'."</a> ";
                for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
                echo "<a href='index.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
                };
                echo "<a href='index.php?page=$total_pages'>".'Last Page'."</a>";
    }
    }
}


//GETTING THE PRODUCTS BY CATEGORIES
function getCatPro(){
    if(isset($_GET['cat'])){
        $cat_id = $_GET['cat'];
        global $con;
        $per_page=9;
        if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
        $page = $_GET["page"];
        }
        else {
        $page=1;
        }
        $start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM products where product_cat='$cat_id' order by product_id DESC LIMIT $start_from, $per_page";
        $result = mysqli_query ($con, $query);
        while ($row_cat_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $pro_title = $row_cat_pro['product_title'];
            $pro_image = $row_cat_pro['product_image'];

            echo "<div id='product'>
                    <h3>$pro_title</h3>
                    <img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_image' width='135' height='145'/>
                  </div>";
        }
        $query = "select * from products where product_cat='$cat_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        $total_records = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);
            echo "<a href='index.php?page=1'>".'First Page'."</a> ";
            for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {
            echo "<a href='index.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
            };
            echo "<a href='index.php?page=$total_pages'>".'Last Page'."</a>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Consult http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php apply that to your code and tell us what pops up. These are essential tools to use during development.

Comment: it's not error sir, just a beginner play :-) just don't know how to improve this to make it work: <a href='index.php?cat=$cat_id'>$cat_title</a>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question as far as I could guess your problem. However, add code and description so that more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify getCatPro() and concatenate the `cat` parameter to the links. For example:

```
echo "<a href='index.php?page=".$i."&cat=".$cat_id."'>".$i."</a> ";
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: _Oh geez thanks. Its works.
It's really the answer what i need
You're Amazing, bro. Thank you, thank you and thank you.

Actually this is for my shop, some customers suggested me to make it online.
And here i'm, just trying to understand about HTML, CSS, Javascript and PHP just 2 weeks ago.
With your help, i'm almost finished with all this code, it's really really helpful, bro, thanks a lot.
I have one more issue left to draw. Would you help me?
Should i make a new topic, or just write to the next comment?
I’ll be forever thankful for your answer :-)

Comment: Just help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39067267/how-to-take-out-the-anchor-element-from-echo-functions-php-and-place-it-to-bod