# How to take out the anchor element from echo (functions.php) and place it to body (index.php)?

Tags: php, html

How to take out the anchor element from echo (functions.php) and place it to body (index.php)?
PS: Newbie here guys, just trying to understand about HTML, CSS, Javascript and PHP about 2 weeks ago.. just imagine what i learned so far, please don't make it difficult to understand.. just write it :-)
Thanks.

```
<!--index.php-->
    <!doctype html>
    <?php include ("functions/functions.php"); ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <ul id="cats">
          <?php getCats(); ?>
        </ul>

    </body>
    </html>


//functions.php
    <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","justLearning");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
       echo "The connection was not established: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    function getCats(){
        global $con;
        $get_cats = "select * from categories";
        $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);
        while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
            $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
            $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];
        echo "<a href='index.php?cat=$cat_id'>$cat_title</a>";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *anchor element* ?

Comment: As an experiment temporarily put `exit('OK');` at the top of `functions.php` and then run `index.php` in the browser... If you do NOT see `OK` then you need to address the `includes_path`

Comment: I couldn't understand your question. When you call the function `getCats();` in *index.php* page, the links i.e. anchor tags will get automatically displayed the `<body>` section. Isn't what you want?

Comment: Return an array and use foreach()

Comment: by the way you're missing <li></li> tags

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `<li></li>` in your code

You need to learn to return an array and to use foreach():

```
  <!doctype html>
  <?php include_once("functions/functions.php"); ?>
  <html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
<ul id="cats">
<?
     $cats = getCats();        
     foreach($cats as $cat){
        echo "<li><a href='index.php?cat=$cat[cat_id]'>$cat[cat_title]</a></li>";
     }    
?>
<ul>
</body>
</html>
    function getCats(){
    global $con;
    $get_cats = "select * from categories";
    $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);
    while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
        $cats[]=$row_cats;
    }
  return $cats;
}
```

Comment: ok. i got it. but the question is can i remove the <a href=  and just echo from:  'index.php?cat=$cat_id'>$cat_title ?

Comment: Yes and no. you can set a string $start_link = "<li><a href='index.php?"; and $end_link = "</a></li>";  then you can change the for each to $start_link .$cat[cat_id]."'>".$cat[cat_title].$end_link;

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try something like this, if you really want to move the < a > elements to the body.However I think that the way you did it was better (there is no reason to move them to the body):

```
<!--index.php-->
<!doctype html>
<?php include_once("functions/functions.php"); ?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

    <ul id="cats">
      <?php 
        $get_cats = "select * from categories";
        $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);
        while ($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats))
        {
           $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
           $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];
      ?>

    <a href='index.php?cat=<?php echo $cat_id;?>'><?php echo $cat_title;?></a>

    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </ul>

</body>
```

And in functions.php you just need to leave the mysql connection object:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","justLearning");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
   echo "The connection was not established: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Comment: that's not what i mean. i want it's seperate between php code and html code. I mean how can i make like this:         <ul id="cats">  <?php getCats(); ?> </ul> in index.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here but I reckon the problem is that the `includes_path` is set to the default and the included file isn't being found???

```
<?php 
    set_include_path( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/functions/' );
    include_once( "functions.php" );
?>

<!--index.php-->
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <title>There must be a title to be considered VALID html</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="cats">
          <?php 
            getCats();
          ?>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have no error actually. i just need to write a clean code with a short php code in html body and a little bit code in php page.  It is possible?